# How to change the user-facing label for a Commerce payment option?

Tags: commerce

I'm using Commerce Braintree as a payment method, which accepts both credit cards and PayPal. Currently it looks like this, which some users are getting confused by since it's not clear that the PayPal button is an *alternative* to the credit card info options:

[image]

I'm getting worrying confused customer comments like "But I don't have a PayPal credit card number", so I'd like to edit this label so that it informs the users that they are being presented with two options (PayPal *or* credit card), but I can't find any way to:

- There's nothing in the UI
- The [feature request to enable it was rejected](https://www.drupal.org/node/995586), a [follow up request is incomplete](https://www.drupal.org/node/1806540)
- [A suggestion to use hook_form_alter](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/189767/how-to-change-option-label-with-hook-form-alter) doesn't work with all payment methods
- I don't want to use string overrides because it's too blunt a tool, replacing "Credit card" everywhere would have unfortunate consequences elsewhere

How do I this be done?

Answer (score 1):

I wasn't expecting something so basic to require an entire extra module, but apparently it does:

- Download and install [Commerce Payment Alter](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_payment_alter)
- Set new labels at the admin page admin/commerce/config/payment-methods/alter

Don't forget to document for administrators that they need to go to a whole different page if they want to rename a payment method's user facing label.